# Wireless Adapter not Recognized After Routine Update

Tags: drivers, wireless, kernel, 22.04

I just did a standard kernel update and now suddenly my wireless does not work any more, with an error "no wireless adapter recognized".

Here were things tried:

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED      
       description: Network controller
       product: RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:80500000-8050ffff
```

So it can see the RTL8821CE adapter here, but it won't engage. I tried doing the steps to re-install the driver and got this:

```
zev@zev-HP-Laptop-15-dy1xxx:~/rtl8821ce$ sudo ./dkms-install.shAbout to run dkms install steps...
Error! DKMS tree already contains: rtl8821ce-v5.5.2_34066.20200325
You cannot add the same module/version combo more than once.


Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel. Skipping...


Building module:
cleaning build area...
'make' -j8 KVER=6.2.0-26-generic.......(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl8821ce: v5.5.2_34066.20200325 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.2.0-26-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325/build/make.log for more information.


Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel. Skipping...


Building module:
cleaning build area...
'make' -j8 KVER=6.2.0-26-generic.......(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl8821ce: v5.5.2_34066.20200325 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.2.0-26-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325/build/make.log for more information.
Finished running dkms install steps.
```

To no effect. I'm not really sure what to do next. It is pretty annoying when just doing a regular old "apt dist-upgrade" breaks wifi.

The wireless diagnosis script gives this:

https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/KY9cTt7YZD/

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, apparently the guides I mentioned forgot to say "after reinstalling the driver, you have to reboot" -- that's all it took.